# Game of Set Puzzle

Tags: code-golf

May be you know [the game of Set](http://www.setgame.com/set/daily_puzzle) (a wonderful game for kids btw) a card game with 81 cards, where each card has a figure on it with 4 different attributes (form , number, colour and fill). Each attribute has 3 different values:

```
form: wave, oval, diamond
colour: red, purple, and green
number: 1, 2, 3
fill: none, dashed, opaque.
```

12 cards are laid open on the table and now the challenge is to indicate sets. A set consists of three cards where every attribute value occurs 0, 1 or 3 times. having 2 cards with red figures, or opaque, or 1 number is no good. See the [supplied](http://www.setgame.com/set/daily_puzzle) link for a more visual explanation.

I do envision a code for a card where all attributes are encoded so

```
"WP2N"
```

stands for

```
2 Purple Waves with No fill
```

[image]

Together with for instance `OR1N` and `DG3N`

[image] and [image]

it is a set (3 different forms, 3 different colors, 3 different number, 1 fill).

Input is space delimited string of unique codes (randomly chosen out of 81 possible codes) representing cards.

```
"OR1N WP2N DG3N DR1D WG3S WG1N WR2D WP3N DR2O DR2D OG3O OR2D"
```

The solution must indicate all possible sets within the given collection. So

```
OR1N, WP2N, DG3N
```

must be part of the solution together with all other sets.

Comment: Sounds promising, but please specify more precisely what kind of input data needs to be handled (stdin, file, parameter) and how the input and output data will look like. Also provide a visual representation (screenshot or similar) of a sample run.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking" because 1. We have no idea what the input or output is supposed to be, and 2. There's no objective winning criterion.  If you edit your question to include these, I may retract my close vote.

Comment: I extended my explanation

Comment: I have retracted my close vote and upvoted this; it's very interesting! :)

Comment: Still missing a objective winning criterion.

Comment: This is labelled a code-challenge, which usually indicates *not* code golf. Is that intentional? If not, then the label should be changed (and the description should mention code golf). If it is intentional, then as @Howard notes an objective winning criterion should be described.

Comment: By the way, your sample has `DR1D` twice; is that intentional?

Comment: The 2nd DR1D has been modified. The tag has also been changed code-golf, although I'm personally more interested in seeing the shortest readable code, showing of language features.

Comment: The hell do you mean by "game for kids"?

Comment: Waitaminute... there are 4 different 4th letters: N, D, S, and O.

Comment: While you address @boothby's very good point, can we make the alphabet for shading: {N, S, F} i.e. Non-filled, Striped, Filled. That way, there is no possible confusion even across attributes.

Comment: @flodel there are possible savings to be had if the alphabets overlap...

Comment: @boothby: I would have said the opposite. If the alphabets don't overlap, for every candidate set, you can just count how many times each letter or number shows up: the set is valid if and only if no number or letter appears twice.

Comment: @flodel see my second solution which takes advantage of an overlap.

Comment: @flodel In any case it usually is not a good idea to change a question in a way that excludes or includes a complete class of solutions, especially when several answers are provided already.

Comment: @flodel I clearly see your points and I do realize it's a whole different exercise if the value attributes become unique. However given the amount of answers and effort people put into it, I do agree with Howard and I think it's not fair to update the question at this point.

Comment: @boothby, its a physical card game which you can buy in a shop or online. Its easy to explain to everyone also kids, and it helps to keep a bunch of indoor kids quiet for at least a few minutes.

Comment: I disagree that it is unfair to update the question.  With the exception of my (non-competitive) answer, nobody actually checks what the letters are.  Thus, [DG3N WG3S OG3O] is getting reported as a 'set'.  That's wrong.  Future answers will be improved by a corrected question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>98</s> <s>81</s> 80 characters

```
$*.combination(3).map{|c|puts c*?,if(0..3).all?{|i|c.map{|x|x[i]}.uniq.size!=2}}
```

Sample run (using your example data):

```
c:\a\ruby>set.rb OR1N WP2N DG3N DR1D WG3S WG1N WR2D WP3N DR2O DR1D OG3O OR2D
OR1N,WP2N,DG3N
WP2N,DR1D,OG3O
WP2N,DR1D,OG3O
DG3N,WG3S,OG3O
```

It outputs `WP2N,DR1D,OG3O` twice because you have two `DR1D`s in your sample data.

Explanation:

`$*.combination(3).map{|c|` - each combination of 3 cards
`puts c*?,if` - output the set, if...
`(0..3).all?{|i|` - if all of the numbers from 0 to 3 (the indeces of the properties in the string) evaluate to `true` when passed into this block
`c.map{|x|x[i]}` - take the `i`th index of each string
`.uniq.size!=2}` - if the amount of unique properties (form, color, etc.) is not 2 (so, 1 or 3)

Comment: Assuming this challenge will become codegolf, may I propose two improvements: a) get rid of `end` plus several line breaks: transform `if ... puts ... end` into `puts ... if ...` b) all can take a block, thus `x.map{}.all?` is equal to `x.all?{}`

Comment: @How Thanks, I'll make those improvements when I get to a computer.

Comment: @Howard Edited to include both. Thanks!

Comment: Also remove the space after `if`.

Comment: I like the ruby solution, short, concise and more or less readable

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <s>93 92 93 82 76</s> 73

```
f={}⋃Select[StringSplit@#~Subsets~{3}, FreeQ[Tally/@(Characters@#^T),2]&]&
```

**The Logic**

`StringSplit@#~Subsets~{3}` produces a list of  3-card subsets.  Each triple such as:

{{"D", "G", "3", "N"}, {"W", "G", "3", "S"}, {"O", "G", "3", "O"}}

or

[image: array 1]

is then  transposed,

[image: array 2]

and `Tally/@(Characters@#^T)` tallies the number of distinct items in each row.

```
{3,1,1,3}
```

3 corresponds to "all different"; 1 corresponds to "all same".

`FreeQ[...,2]` determines whether 2 cards of the same type or in the triple.
If 2 is not among the tallies, then the three cards are a "set", according to Game of Set rules.

---

**Usage**

```
f["OR1N WP2N DG3N DR1D WG3S WG1N WR2D WP3N DR2O DR1D OG3O OR2D"]
```

> {{"DG3N", "WG3S", "OG3O"}, {"OR1N", "WP2N", "DG3N"}, {"WP2N", "DR1D", 
>     "OG3O"}}

Comment: It can be shorter if duplicates are allowed. `f=Select[StringSplit@#~Subsets~{3},FreeQ[Tally/@Thread@Characters@#,2]&]&` Output will be `{{"OR1N", "WP2N", "DG3N"}, {"WP2N","DR1D", "OG3O"}, {"WP2N", "DR1D", "OG3O"}, {"DG3N", "WG3S", "OG3O"}}`

Comment: Very clever way to check for "all same" or "all different"!

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 73

```
f = Select[StringSplit@#~Subsets~{3}, FreeQ[Tally /@ Thread@Characters@#, 2] &] &
```

**Usage**

```
f["OR1N WP2N DG3N DR1D WG3S WG1N WR2D WP3N DR2O DR1D OG3O OR2D"]
```

> {{"OR1N", "WP2N", "DG3N"}, {"WP2N", "DR1D", "OG3O"}, {"WP2N", "DR1D", "OG3O"}, {"DG3N", "WG3S", "OG3O"}}

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
ṇ₁⊇Ṫz{=|≠}ᵐz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa7EVQOEYUoPd3XaP2rb8Kip6eG2BUDOw60THnUsf7hjG5BdC@T8f7iz/VFT46Ou9oc7V1VV29Y86lwAEq/6/z9ayT/I0E8hPMDIT8HF3RhIBBm6KIS7GwcDCZBEkBGQGwCWMPIHES4K/u7G/gr@QJaSjpJxcUGGglFKUaqCYX5BMZBIzwASRUCx4nQwF0iAZYtBEilArlEKWEl6qlIsAA)

Takes input through the input variable and [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) the output through the output variable.

Second test case taken from a [recently closed duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195023/play-the-card-game-set) in its encoding, since this solution doesn't really care what anything actually means.

```
                The output variable is
  ⊇             a subsequence
   Ṫ            of length 3
ṇ₁              of the input split on spaces,
    z      z    the columns of which
     {   }ᵐ     are all
       |        either
      =         the same element repeated,
        ≠       or entirely free of duplicates.
```

Comment: [+1 byte if output can't be a list of character lists, as opposed to a list of strings](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa7EVQOEYUoPd3XaP2rb8Kip6eG2BUDOw60THnUsf7hjG5BdC@T8f7iz/VFT46Ou9oc7V@lVVdvWPOpcUAtR9f9/tJJ/kKGfQniAkZ@Ci7sxkAgydFEIdzcOBhIgiSAjIDcALGHkDyJcFPzdjf0V/IEsJR0l4@KCDAWjlKJUBcP8gmIgkZ4BJIqAYsXpYC6QAMsWgyRSgFyjFLCS9FSlWAA)

Answer (score 3):

#### GolfScript, 53 characters

```
" "/:w,,{:a,{:^,{a^]{w=}%.0\zip{.&,2=|}/!{.p}*;}/}/}/
```

Input must be provided on STDIN, [example online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJPUjFOIFdQMk4gREczTiBEUjFEIFdHM1MgV0cxTiBXUjJEIFdQM04gRFIyTyBEUjJEIE9HM08gT1IyRCIKCiIgIi86dywsezphLHs6Xix7YV5de3c9fSUuMFx6aXB7LiYsMj18fS8hey5wfSo7fS99L30vCg%3D%3D&run=true):

```
> OR1N WP2N DG3N DR1D WG3S WG1N WR2D WP3N DR2O DR2D OG3O OR2D
["OR1N" "DG3N" "WP2N"]
["WP2N" "OG3O" "DR1D"]
["DG3N" "OG3O" "WG3S"]
["WR2D" "OR2D" "DR2D"]
```

Commented code:

```
" "/:w          # split the input at spaces and assign it to variable w
,,              # create the array [0..n-1] (n being the length of w)
{:a,{:^,{       # three nested loops: a=0..n-1, ^=0..a-1, _=0..b-1 
                # (third loop has no variable assigned but just pushes on stack)
    a^]         # make an array [a,^,_] of the three loop variables
    {w=}%       # take the corresponding list items, i.e. [w[a],w[^],w[_]]
    .0\         # push zero, add duplicate of the the array
    zip         # zip transposes the array, thus [OR1N WP2N DG3N] -> [OWD RPG 123 NNN]
    {           # loop over those entries
      .&        # unique
      ,2=       # length equals 2?
      |         # "or" with top of stack (two zero pushed before)
    }/          # end of loop, on stack remains the results of the "or"s
    !{.p}*      # if no length of 2 is there, make a copy of the set and print it
    ;           # discard stack item
}/}/}/          # closing the three nested loops
```

Comment: I would say a clear winner for a code-golf. Hower totally unreadable..

Comment: @drjerry Compared with other golfscript code it's quite readable. E.g. it contains only plain loops and no advanced tricks. I'll add an explanation of the code later.

Comment: `0\zip{.&,2=|}/!` can be shortened to `zip{.&,}%2&!`

Answer (score 1):

### javascript <s>323</s> 313

```
function a(b){d=h=[];c=e=f=0;for(i in b){for(j in b){for(k in b[i]){if(b[i][k]==b[j][k]){if(c+f<4)c++;else if(c==4){h+=b[j];if(h.length=3)return h}}else{for(l in d){for(m in d[l]){g=f;if(d[l][2]==i){if(d[l][3]==k)if(b[j][k]!=d[l][0]&&b[j][k]!=d[l][1])f++;}else{continue}}if(g==f)d[e++]=[b[i][k],b[j][k],j,k]}}}}}}
```

its a function that takes a array of objects, and returns a array of objects.

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/uQeMy/3/) (with tidy-up).

Comment: You don't have to declare variables...

Comment: @Doorknob i take it back, you are right. edited. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### APL(IBM), 76

```
⍉¨x/⍨{{⍵≡1⌽⍵}⍵=1⌽⍵}¨x←⊃¨(∘.,/3⍴⊂⍪¨(' '≠y)⊂y←⍞)⌷⍨¨z/⍨∧/¨2</¨z←,⍳3⍴12
```

I don't have IBM APL, but I believe this will work.

**Sample run (Emulating IBM APL in Dyalog APL)**

```
OR1N WP2N DG3N DR1D WG3S WG1N WR2D WP3N DR2O DR1D OG3O OR2D
 OR1N  WP2N  WP2N  DG3N 
 WP2N  DR1D  DR1D  WG3S 
 DG3N  OG3O  OG3O  OG3O
```

Comment: First time I see apl code thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 71

If `C` is a string, say `"OR1N WP2N DG3N DR1D WG3S WG1N WR2D WP3N DR2O DR1D OG3O OR2D"`, execute

```
[c for c in Subsets(C.split(),3)if{1,3}>={len(set(x))for x in zip(*c)}]
```

to get `[{'DR1D', 'OG3O', 'WP2N'}, {'DR2D', 'WR2D', 'OR2D'}, {'WG3S', 'OG3O',
'DG3N'}, {'DG3N', 'WP2N', 'OR1N'}]`

And here's a very different approach using the interpretation that a Set is a projective line in `GF(3)^4`:

```
[c for c in Subsets(C.split(),3)if sum(matrix(3,map('WODRPG123N'.find,''.join(c))))%3==0]
```

I was a little annoyed that `D` was used twice... until I figured how to abuse that.  But even better, I abuse the `find` method, too. `str.find` returns -1 if a letter isn't found.  Since `-1 = 2 mod 3`, the letter `S` is handled appropriately because it doesn't occur in `'WODRPG123N'`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 99 bytes

```python
lambda A:[a for a in combinations(A,3)if all(len(set(t))-2for t in zip(*a))]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxCsIwFEV3v@LhlBQVmmyCQ6HQrSl16KAOqTb4IE1C8hb9@Zq4HO7lnPCht3diM5f7ZvU6vzQ055sG4yNoQAdPv87oNKF3iTUHydGAtpbZxbG0ECPOj6LUVOovBlZpzh87E/0KSEsk720CXIOPVG0hoiMwbK/GuodpED20ncwY6xamTl4zihhFvsNfCFXQguqkApXX/pSCRWKcbz8)